# Using fgets && sscanf to read from an array

Tags: c, arrays, input, scanf

I have a text file which looks like :

```
C M 2/1/2015 18280 "2107070770"
C U 2/1/2015 18300 "2107070770"
```

The text file has multiple lines . I am trying to store
each line into a string array and then store each value 
into variables , i want to work with.
(I open fopen the file successfully)

I store each line with the following way :

```
char line[50];
char *lines[40];
char *eof ; 
int i ; 
while( (eof = fgets(line, 50, in)) != NULL )
{
    lines[i] = strdup(eof);
    i++;
}
```

Then , I am trying to store each value into variables , with the following way:

```
for( j = 0; j <= 39 ; j++)
{
    sscanf( lines[j], "%c %c %d/%d/%d %d %s", &(operation), &(destination), &(day) , &(month) , &(year) , &(name)) ;    

    /*printf("%s\n", lines[j]);*/
}
```

So, I can work on each line separately .
My code stores each line into the array successfully, but after
adding the sscanf function it stops working without any output.
What have i done wrong ?

Comment: `while( (eof = fgets(line, 50, in)) != NULL )` --> `while (fgets(line, 50, in))`, and with the last argument of `scanf` you don't need to pass an address because `name` is already (or decays into) a pointer.

Comment: `i` is not initialized here.. automatic variables are not initialized by default.

Comment: Seven conversion specifiers. Six variables. Undefined behaviour. You die. ;-)

Comment: i am dead ! x) thanks !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the line

```
C U 2/1/2015 18300 "2107070770"
```

After the year 2015, you're missing the integer 18300. You have a format specifier in the format string but no corresponding variable to store it.

after operation, destination, day, month, year, **missing_variable**, name

```
//so the right one will be
// assuming name is a char*

int my_int = 0;
for( j = 0; j <= 39 ; j++)
{
    sscanf( lines[j], "%c %c %d/%d/%d %d %s", 
    &(operation), &(destination), &(day) , &(month) , &(year), 
    &(my_int), name) ;    

    /*printf("%s\n", lines[j]);*/
}
```

Comment: thanks alot !! is there any way to ignore the quotation marks \" ?

Comment: That you may need to strip out with a custom function.

Answer (score 0):

Start by checking your file descriptor successfully points to your file

```
if(in==NULL)
  exit(-1); // Hope this is already in the code.
```

Change

```
int i ;
```

to

```
int i=0; // automatic variables are not initialized by default
```

From **ISO/IEC 9899:201x 6.7.9->10**

> If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized
>   explicitly, its value is indeterminate.

As somebody pointer out you have a missing variable in sscanf. If you wish to s tore the entire stuff after the `age`, say `18280 "2107070770"` to string `name` you can do it like:

```
sscanf( lines[j], "%c %c %d/%d/%d %d %[^\t\n]", 
    &(operation), &(destination), &(day) , &(month) , &(year), 
    &(my_int), name) ;
```

Also as somebody has pointed out `name` decays to a pointer, so you don't need to pass it like `&name`

Comment: thanks alot mate !! is there any way to ignore the quotation marks \" ?

Comment: Change `%[^\t\n]` to `%[^"\t\n]`. You can see I have added a quotation mark. This is called a scan-set and using `^` in the beginning we tell scanf to decline taking the characters that follow it.. If you don't use a `^` then it means read only from the set of characters included eg `[a-zA-Z]` reads only the characters in the range